# How to get and iterate through two dimentional list (using foreach I guess) in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want a stored procedure that will put following results into a list and then I can go through each item of list I declared in stored procedure,

first thing first I will take columns using this statement,

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB 
FROM MyTable   // Save it into a two dimensional array or dictionary I guess
```

Then need to do another query within stored procedure for each `columnA` and `columnB` and get back a list of values for `columnC`

```
if exists (
    SELECT ColumnC FROM Table2 
    Where ColumnA = //@ColumnA[i] or something  
    AND SchemeID = //@ColumnB[i] or something)
//then add ColumnC value to a list
else
continue
```

I am new to SQL but have been working on C# for a moment so not sure how to make this stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can insert data from table into temporary table and then write cursor, but it's not good to do so in SQL.
I suggest you to describe what do you want to get at the end of stored procedure.

```
SELECT T2.ColumnC 
FROM Table2 as T2
where
    exists
    (
       select *
       from Table as T1
       where T1.ColumnA = T2.ColumnA and T1.ColumnB = T2.SchemeID
    )
```

Comment: I want a list of values within columnC

Comment: so try query in answer above it should give you all values in ColumnC

Comment: yes you can use `inner join Table as T1 on T1.ColumnA = T2.ColumnA and T1.ColumnB = T2.SchemeID`